# Average of a distinct count by day in Access

Tags: ms-access, count, distinct, average

I'm trying to get an average of a distinct count per day out of an Access 2010 database and nothing I do seems to be working. I've tried using a subquery but I can't figure out how to link it to the main one. The table has a row for every office visit, like this:

```
    patient_id, visit_year, visit_date, dow, doctor_id
    12345, 2012, 3/5/12, Monday, 987
    12567, 2012, 3/5/12, Monday, 986
    12789, 2012, 3/6/12, Tuesday, 987
```

I need to get the average number of doctors available per day of week where year = 2012. In my head this should work but it doesn't: 
Select dow, AVG(COUNT(DISTINCT(doctor_id))) AS AvgDocsInOffice
From visits
WHERE visit_year = 2012
GROUP BY dow

I'm trying to get to this output:

```
    DOW, AvgDocsInOffice
    Monday, 5
    Tuesday, 6
    Wednesday, 4
```

Any ideas? Unfortunately I'm stuck doing this in Access.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT dow, AVG(CntDocsInOffice) AS AvgDocsInOffice FROM
     (SELECT dow, visit_date, COUNT(*) AS CntDocsInOffice FROM
        (SELECT DISTINCT dow, visit_date, doctor_id FROM
            visits
         WHERE visit_year = 2012)
      GROUP BY dow, visit_date)
GROUP BY dow;
```

The inner most SELECT selects unique doctors per day.
The next outer SELECT counts the number of unique doctors per day.
The outer most SELECT finally calculates the average doctor count per day of week.

Comment: @Remou: Good point. It depends if `doctor_id` is a required field.

Comment: Thanks - this worked great! doctor_id is required so no problems there. Three select statements, wow. I think I will spend the rest of the afternoon wrapping my head around this.

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
SELECT q.dow,
       Avg(q.countofdoctor_id) AS avgofcountofdoctor_id
FROM   (SELECT v.visit_date,
               v.dow,
               COUNT(v.doctor_id) AS countofdoctor_id
        FROM   (SELECT DISTINCT visit_date,
                                dow,
                                doctor_id
                FROM   visits
                WHERE  visit_year = 2012) AS v
        GROUP  BY v.visit_date,
                  v.dow) AS q
GROUP  BY q.dow;
```

Comment: This one works too, thanks! I got the same results as I did with Oliver Jacot-Descombes' code. I'm not sure if one of these is more efficient than the other or just a different way to do the same thing. But it helps to see it both ways. Wish I could mark them both as my answer.